# C++ unable to call std::endl

Tags: c++, string, macros

Framed the question better manner:

Have a logger C++ class which has the << operator overloaded to accept ints, strings..

```
logR <<"Test"<<endl
```

Now the endl had been defined as macro

```
#define endl "\n\r"
```

Now in any .cpp file if i included this logger class's header file i used to get compilation error for using endl.

Found a fix for this instead of defining macro endl, I overloaded operator to receive the endl() itself.
Thanks for the inputs it helped in solving the issue.

Comment: `std::endl` is defined in `<ostream>`. Do you have it imported?

Comment: First question: Why you want to do that? `std::endl` works well. Explanation of error: `#define` is preprocessor directive which are executed before compilation, so every occurence of `endl` is replaced with `"\n\r"`

Comment: On a totally unrelated note: The common way for carriage-return and newline is in *that* order, i.e. `"\r\n"`. Many standards specifies it as that, in that order.

Comment: For the sake of "yeah, it works" you might actually do something like `#define endOfTheLine std::endl`.

Comment: @Macias std::endl does only \n  i need something \n\r or \r\n as pointed out.
reason being the new log shud start from beginning of next line not underneath end of prev line

Comment: Normally the library should translate `'\n'` into `"\r\n"` for ***text*** streams on systems that require it. That's why you have things like text and binary mode when opening a stream, so the library should know if it should do the translation. Perhaps you should ask about why that translation isn't made for your stream in a separate question? With a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the standard [N4687](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4687.pdf):

**20.5.4.3.2 Macro names**

> 1 A translation unit that includes a standard library header **shall not
>     #define or #undef names declared in any standard library header**.
>
> 2 A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically
>     identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 4, or to the
>     attribute-tokens described in 10.6.

So what you are trying to do is prohibited by the standard!

Additionally in this specific case it won't work because you are substituting `endl` for a string of some sort, causing the preprocessor to generate this: `std::"\n\r"` which causes the compilation to fail.

---

If you wan't to replace `std::endl` by `"\r\n"` (BTW: not `"\n\r"`) then do it by hand or write a script to do it.

Comment: I'd add that it doesn't work in this case not because it's UB, but because it becomes `std::"blah"`, which is nonsense.

Comment: Ok agreed, the std::endl supports only "\n"
Am using it for logging so we need "\n\r" else teh new log starts at the next line beginning from where prvious line ended underneath it And not from beginning of next line.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the feedback. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @sach What do you use to view the logs? Maybe get a better text editor that shows `\n` properly instead?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the logs are written to files and or printed on consoles of hardware devices

Comment: @sach: note that `std::endl` inserts a `'\n'` character. However, when opening a file stream in text mode (i.e., non-`std::ios_base::binary` mode) each `'\n'` character is translated into the platform's end of line sequence - independent on any other character being inserted which would also complete the end of line sequence.

Comment: @DietmarKühl True that. Here are the links to the cppreference for [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) and [`std::basic_ios::widen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/widen) so that the OP can learn how they work.

Comment: @DietmarKühl et all Thanks a lot for the information.

Answer (score 3):

As was pointed out already, you are not allowed to define a macro with the name `endl`. However, you are allowed to declare a varaiable with the name `endl` (outside namespace `std` obviously). So you could have

```
// where the macro is currently define:
extern char const endl[3];

// in a suitable source file including the header with the above declaration:
char const endl[3] = "\n\r";
```

The observed behavior should be the same as using the macro except that this declaration can coexist with `std::endl`. That does assume that you don''t use `L endl` with which I'd consider rather odd. Thinking of it, I can imagine you are using `T(endl)` which nearly adds this `L` but accually concatenates `L` to the name. If so, you'd just also add

```
extern wchar_t const Lendl[];
```

with a corresponding definition.

If you want to use your `endl` just like `std::endl` is used but with some different behavior, I'd recommend defining it in a similar way, too:

```
template <typename cT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& endl(std::basic_ostream<cT, Traits>& out) {
    return out << out.widen('\n') << out.widen('\r');
}
```

Of course, when sending a `'\n'` character to a `std::ofstream` (or an `std::wofstream`) opened in text mode (i.e., without using `std::ios_base::binary`) it gets translated into the [platform specific] end of line sequence.